# Spark 1.4.0 org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'probability' given input columns

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am currently using `Spark 1.4.0`, and started using the `ML pipeline framework`.

I ran the example program **"ml.JavaSimpleTextClassificationPipeline"** which uses the `LogisticRegression`. But I wanted to do multiclass classification, so I used `DecisionTreeClassifier` present in the `org.apache.spark.ml.classification` package.

The model got trained properly using the `fit` method, but when testing the model using the `print` statement from above example, I am getting following error that **'probability'** column is not present.

Is this column present only for `LogisticRegression`? If so can I see what are the possible columns present after `DecisionTreeClassifier` predicts the output?

Also, one morething how can I convert the predicted output back to String format if I am using `StringIndexer`.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'probability' given input columns id, prediction, labelStr, data, features, words, label;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:63) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:52) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:286) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:286) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:51) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:285) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$transformExpressionUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:108) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlan.scala:123) 
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) 
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) 
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59) 
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47) 
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244) 
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlan.scala:122) 
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328) 
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727) 
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157) 
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48) 
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103) 
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47) 
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273) 
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157) 
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265) 
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157) 
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252) 
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:127) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:52) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:50) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:98) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:50) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:42) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(SQLContext.scala:920) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:131) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$logicalPlanToDataFrame(DataFrame.scala:154) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.select(DataFrame.scala:595) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.select(DataFrame.scala:611) 
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.select(DataFrame.scala:611) 
    at com.xxx.ml.xxx.execute(xxx.java:129)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because "probability" is not a column in your rdd.  If you would like to operate on the probability field, you should add it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, but the example I mentioned also did not add any column with name 'probability'

Comment: This 'probability' column is present in DecisionTree classifier of spark 1.6.1 and now I am able to use it, document ref:https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#decision-trees